# Table of pdfs, cdfs, moments

Tags: reference-request, statistics

Is there a table online (or perhaps in a book) that you would recommend for looking up probability density functions, cumulative distribution functions, moments, etc. for known distributions?

Comment: I use [this](http://danielsoper.com/statcalc3/default.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- Johnson, Kotz, Balakrishnan *Continuous Univariate Distributions* ([two](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471584959) [volumes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471584940))
- Johnson, Kemp, Kotz *[Univariate Discrete Distributions](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=7S6Qhs0ZxWoC)*
- Kotz, Balakrishnan, Johnson *[Continuous Multivariate Distributions: Models and applications](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=oRz08PkCk-4C)*
- Forbes, Evans, Hastings, Peacock *[Statistical Distributions](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=sblRcawC9BYC)*
- Krishnamoorthy *[Handbook of Statistical Distributions with Applications](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=FEE8D1tRl30C)*

I'm sure there are others I missed...